# Uhlhorn's "On the connection between transformations in classical mechanics and ..."?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, specific-reference, phase-space

I've looked around online for quite a while for the following paper, but have only been able to find people citing it. And, [as you can see](http://www.speciation.net/Database/Journals/Arkiv-foer-Fysik-;i771), the journal itself hasn't made their papers available, so... does anyone happen to have a copy? (Or, if all else fails, know of another reference which covers the material?)

U. Uhlhorn, Arkiv för Fysik 11, 87-100 (1956).

"On the connection between transformations in classical mechanics and in quantum mechanics and the phase space representation of quantum mechanics"

Comment: Did you manage to get it?

Comment: The original answer has annulled itself.  I bountied it hoping some reader may have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a copy somewhere, if anyone needs it at any point....

https://www.docdroid.net/8aLKMOu/uhlhorn-on-the-connection-between-transformations-in-classical-mechanics-and-in-quantum-mechanics-and-the-phase-space-representation-of-quantum-mechanics.pdf.html

Comment: Unfortunately currently the link is dead. Would it be possible to revive it?

Comment: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე. I bountied it, keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: Oh, come one. I also can't find it anywhere.